# android array adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is changing position of items

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have an array adapter of a listView with a custom layout with multiple child elements. in `getView()` I am binding these child view to a viewHolder class like below:

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        // get item for selected view
        Item item = getItem(position);

        // if cell is exists - reuse it, if not - create the new one from resource
        FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (cell == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            cell = (FoldingCell) vi.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);

            viewHolder.delete = cell.findViewById(R.id.DeleteICN);
            viewHolder.delete.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.rename = cell.findViewById(R.id.renameBtn);
            viewHolder.rename.setTag(position);
            cell.setTag(viewHolder);

         ...
         ...

}
public void setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(View.OnClickListener defaultRequestBtnClickListener) {
    this.defaultRequestBtnClickListener = defaultRequestBtnClickListener;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    ConstraintLayout delete;
    ConstraintLayout rename;
 }
```

I am setting a Tag(position) on the `delete` and `rename` views so If I delete or rename a particular element(onclick) I can find it easily with the tag.

The problem is that when I go and click the rename or delete button with the below code:

```
 adapter.setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){              

                 Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), " "+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 if(v.getId() == R.id.renameBtn){

                     System.out.println(v.getTag()); 
                     Item item = adapter.getItem(v.getTag());

                     //this changes a textView in the same listview element 
                     item.setTitle("newTitle");               

                 }
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }
         });
```

The displayed toast is changing value when clicking on same element more than once. If however, I comment out `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the toast keeps the same value for the same element. why is that?

If there is any other code that I should be posting let me know.

Comment: You need to move the `setTag(position)` calls to after the `if-else`. As you have it now, they're only being set when the `View` is first created. When they start being recycled, they don't get their positions updated.

Comment: yep that worked! I knew it had to be something simple.